# How can I determine if a client SSH connection has a tty associated with it?

Tags: linux, unix, sshd, tty, pam

Im writing a PAM module to handle authentication (server side - sshd) and I have to know if an ssh client is a tty (interactive) or not (non interactive).

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking for `$SSH_TTY`, but that isn't reliable.

```
$ ssh -6 fedoraplug.local
Last login: ......
-$ echo "${!SSH*}"
SSH_CLIENT SSH_CONNECTION SSH_TTY
-$ exit
$ ssh -6 fedoraplug.local 'echo "${!SSH*}"'
SSH_CLIENT SSH_CONNECTION
$ ssh -t -6 fedoraplug.local 'echo "${!SSH*}"'
SSH_CLIENT SSH_CONNECTION SSH_TTY
Connection to fedoraplug.local closed.
```

Comment: isnt that on the client side? Im on the server side (sshd)

Comment: Uh, no, that's done on the server.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side of things, you can use the `tty` command ([manpage here](http://ss64.com/bash/tty.html)).  Assuming the session is interactive, this command would return something like:

```
breakthrough@lt0:~$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

However, if the client is **not** interactive/tty-based, the command will return:

```
not a tty
```

---

For actually *writing* a PAM module, while `tty` does provide some exit codes that you can use, it's unlikely that you can use the `tty` command directly as a syscall; instead, you should take a look at [the `ttyname()` (or `ttyname_r()`) function](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_ttyname_r.htm).

You can see a sample implementation of [this function here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/tty/ttyname.c.html) which covers some general use cases.  While it should be sufficient to see if a valid ttyname was returned, best practice would be to check if the error `ENOTTY` was raised, indicating that the passed file descriptor does not refer to a terminal device.

Comment: Unless `-t` is passed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams even a [pseudo-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) emulates a full text terminal, so one would expect even a non-interactive session invoked with this **should** indicate that the session is TTY regardless...

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in C:

```
man isatty
```

DESCRIPTION
       The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.

RETURN VALUE
       isatty()  returns  1  if fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal; otherwise 0 is returned,
       and errno is set to indicate the error.